# sql select statements with having statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables employee table and branch table. Employee table contains all information like empid, name, salary, datehired, branchcode, supervisor and my branch table contains branchcode, name, budget and town. My question is how do you list branches (branch code only) with more than 5 employees? Anyone smart has an idea?

Comment: Please provide the table structures, along with what you have tried.  Your effort motivates people here to help you learn.

Comment: I'd say no one is going to help you without seeing what you've tried first, but I'm consistently proven wrong in that regard.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables This surprises me too.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the branchcodes that have more than 5 employees, and no other branch information you can simply do:

```
SELECT branchcode
FROM employee
GROUP BY branchcode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

Comment: it worked, cant believe i couldnt come up with that:/ thanks

Comment: another one i cant get the stetement right is I have a table that contains empid, name, salary, hiredate, positionand supervisor (which includes empid not the name) how do i list the empid and name of all supervisors ? the output has to have to columns supervisor( and a list of their emid) and their names.

Comment: @user3067155. That is a different question. Please mark this as accepted and add that to a different question. Make sure to include as much information and attempts to solve the problem as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the following query is what you are after:

```
SELECT b.branchcode
FROM employee AS e
  INNER JOIN branch AS b
  ON e.branchcode = b.branchcode
GROUP BY b.branchcode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

**YOU ADDITIONALLY ASKED:**

I have a table that contains empid, name, salary, hiredate, positionand supervisor (which includes empid not the name) how do i list the empid and name of all supervisors ? the output has to have to columns supervisor( and a list of their emid) and their names.

**MY ADDITIONAL ANSWER:**

I am not fully understanding what you are saying but maybe this will help:

```
SELECT e1.empid AS EmpID, e1.name AS EmpName, 
       e2.empid AS SupervisorID, e2.name AS SupervisorName
FROM mytable AS m
INNER JOIN employee AS e1 ON m.empid = e1.empid
INNER JOIN employee AS e2 ON m.supervisor = e2.empid
```

I don't know the name of the table you are referring to, so in the above example I am using `mytable`.  This assumes that supervisor is a foreign key to `empid` in the `employee` table.  If not and it actually contains the supervisors name then you can remove the second join to the employee table and select `m.supervisor` directly.

Comment: thanks what about that one I have a table that contains empid, name, salary, hiredate, positionand supervisor (which includes empid not the name) how do i list the empid and name of all supervisors ? the output has to have to columns supervisor( and a list of their emid) and their names.